# Choose Step Causes Data Mismatch [GREMLIN API]

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

[image: Structure of a part of my graph database]
The Image above is the structure of a part of my graph database.

What I'm trying to achieve here is that I'm trying to search for product vertices by using the name of the of their related detail vertices.
The Expected output is a list of products with their details that has a name of `test3`.

I am using choose step in my query to handle different values of my vertices.

```
g
.V()
.has('label', 
    within(
        'data_computed_property',
        'data_variable','recipe_ingredient',
        'cost_setting_variable','benefit_analysis_variable',
        'formula',
        'detail'
    )
)
.has('name', 'test3') // this is where i filter out all the detail vertices with a name of `test3`
.where(
    __.in()
    .has('label', 
        within(
            'product',
            'recipe',
            'machine'
        )
    )
    .in()
    .has('id', '13eec000-78fa-41fd-856b-bbc37711b1f0')
)
.project('parent','property')
.by(
    __.in()
    .has('label', 
        within(
            'product',
            'recipe',
            'machine'
        )
    )
    .valueMap(true)
)
.by(
    choose(values('label'))
    .option(
        'detail', 
        project('detail','value')
        .by(valueMap(true))
        .by(
            choose(values('type'))
            .option('string', values('value'))
            .option('number', values('value'))
            .option('date', values('value'))
            .option('formula', out('value').valueMap(true))
            .option('condition', out('value').valueMap(true))
            .option('variable', out('value').valueMap(true))
            .option('element', out('value').valueMap(true))
        )
    )
    .option('data_computed_property', valueMap(true))
    .option('data_variable', valueMap(true))
    .option('recipe_ingredient', valueMap(true))
    .option('cost_setting_variable', valueMap(true))
    .option('benefit_analysis_variable', valueMap(true))
    .option('formula', valueMap(true))
)
```

And this is the output of my query

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "parent" => array:3 [
        "id" => "bee7eaa1-ad6c-436e-9000-7bf4665552d9"
        "label" => "product"
        "name" => array:1 [
          0 => "Product 1"
        ]
        "description" => array:1 [
          0 => ""
        ]
        "pk" => array:1 [
          0 => "13eec000-78fa-41fd-856b-bbc37711b1f0"
        ]
        "sku" => array:1 [
          0 => "1235455"
        ]
    ]
    "property" => array:2 [
      "detail" => array:6 [
        "id" => "5ad33864-25a7-424a-ba8d-a1b3e255d0a9"
        "label" => "detail"
        "name" => array:1 [
          0 => "test3"
        ]
        "type" => array:1 [
          0 => "date"
        ]
        "pk" => array:1 [
          0 => "bee7eaa1-ad6c-436e-9000-7bf4665552d9/detail"
        ]
        "value" => array:1 [
          0 => 1583884800
        ]
      ]
      "value" => 1583884800
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "parent" => array:3 [
        "id" => "25c4cdfd-1845-4696-a427-5814d7adf71c"
        "label" => "product"
        "name" => array:1 [
          0 => "Product 2"
        ]
        "description" => array:1 [
          0 => ""
        ]
        "pk" => array:1 [
          0 => "13eec000-78fa-41fd-856b-bbc37711b1f0"
        ]
        "sku" => array:1 [
          0 => "2569885"
        ]
    ]
    "property" => array:2 [
      "detail" => array:5 [
        "id" => "db15ff37-4b13-4520-8e72-ae9f559f0fdc"
        "label" => "detail"
        "name" => array:1 [
          0 => "test3"
        ]
        "type" => array:1 [
          0 => "variable"
        ]
        "pk" => array:1 [
          0 => "25c4cdfd-1845-4696-a427-5814d7adf71c/detail"
        ]
      ]
      "value" => 1583884800
    ]
  ]
]
```

As you can see, the `value` property for the last element of list is a value that belongs to the first item.

This is how the output is expected to look like

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
      "parent" => array:6 [
        "id" => "bee7eaa1-ad6c-436e-9000-7bf4665552d9"
        "label" => "product"
        "name" => array:1 [
          0 => "Product 1"
        ]
        "description" => array:1 [
          0 => ""
        ]
        "pk" => array:1 [
          0 => "13eec000-78fa-41fd-856b-bbc37711b1f0"
        ]
        "sku" => array:1 [
          0 => "1235455"
        ]
    ]
    "property" => array:2 [
      "detail" => array:6 [
        "id" => "5ad33864-25a7-424a-ba8d-a1b3e255d0a9"
        "label" => "detail"
        "name" => array:1 [
          0 => "test3"
        ]
        "type" => array:1 [
          0 => "date"
        ]
        "pk" => array:1 [
          0 => "bee7eaa1-ad6c-436e-9000-7bf4665552d9/detail"
        ]
        "value" => array:1 [
          0 => 1583884800
        ]
      ]
      "value" => 1583884800
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "parent" => array:3 [
        "id" => "25c4cdfd-1845-4696-a427-5814d7adf71c"
        "label" => "product"
        "name" => array:1 [
          0 => "Product 2"
        ]
        "description" => array:1 [
          0 => ""
        ]
        "pk" => array:1 [
          0 => "13eec000-78fa-41fd-856b-bbc37711b1f0"
        ]
        "sku" => array:1 [
          0 => "2569885"
        ]
    ]
    "property" => array:2 [
      "detail" => array:5 [
        "id" => "db15ff37-4b13-4520-8e72-ae9f559f0fdc"
        "label" => "detail"
        "name" => array:1 [
          0 => "test3"
        ]
        "type" => array:1 [
          0 => "variable"
        ]
        "pk" => array:1 [
          0 => "25c4cdfd-1845-4696-a427-5814d7adf71c/detail"
        ]
      ]
      "value" => [
           "id" => "63b66993-cb5e-4cdb-b7c4-5db069106ac3"
           "label" => "cost_setting_variable"
           "name" => array:1 [
               0 => "07/24/2021-variable"
           ]
           "value" => array:1 [
               0 => "50"
           ]
           "pk" => array:1 [
               0 => "4837194c-fe11-485a-9ef2-54fc0d621059"
           ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Could be some problem with azure-cosmosdb. 

I tried running this with tinkerpop-apache and it runs fine.